# how to split \t in Qt text reading

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

i'm using split to detect some number in a text file in Qt.

```
 QString line = my_file.readLine();
 QStringList list ;
 if(file_format=="csv")
    list=line.split(',', QString::SkipEmptyParts);
 else
    list=line.split('\t', QString::SkipEmptyParts);
```

this code works good for csv file. but for txt file it does not detect any number. what can i do? any idea?
 sample text:

```
-0.0050000000000000001  0.0018503982665486619   1.7510645161290324
```

this detected in line variable in Qt debug

```
-0.0050000000000000001\t0.0018503982665486619\t1.7510645161290324
```

Comment: what do you mean in last comment _this detected in line variable in Qt deb_

Comment: did you mean you _**verified**_ that those are true **Tab**s, if not , why should you assume they are? for testing did you try `\s` (white space) instead of `\t`

Comment: `list = line.split(QRegExp("\\s+"), QString::SkipEmptyParts);`?

Comment: `QByteArray::toHex()` is a great function for investigating stuff like this.

Comment: deb=> debug(edited in original post)

Comment: the problem solved. thanks all and thanks Wiktor Stribiżew. the bug is using '\t' instead of "\t".

Comment: @javad post an answer if you solved it, save time to future readers

Comment: Does it mean `list=line.split("\t", QString::SkipEmptyParts);` works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem solved. thanks all and thanks Wiktor Stribiżew. the bug is using '\t' instead of "\t"